# Image manipulation for a social site in Java or Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, image-processing, playframework-2.0

I'm working on a social website that uses upload of **Images** for **Display Picture** and **Banner** ( as FB Cover)
I am using `AngularJs` on frontend and `Play Framework (JAVA)` on backend.
However, I am not able to find best way to process uploaded image (cropping, resizing, etc).
Should I do it on client side in Javascript or Upload to server and do it in Java ? and which libs, i should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veeery wide question, so we can just give you tips, not an answer...

Anyway last time we completed similar task with [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) + [gm4java](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sharneng/gm4java) + [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) quite nice, of course there is still some coding for you, but IMHO it's good start.

Comment: thanks for answer. I think best is to come up with a solution myself.